# What is the rule of the order of multiple type variables in haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, newtype, type-variables

For example, ParsecT has multiple type variables in its definition.

```
newtype ParsecT s u m a
    = ParsecT {unParser :: forall b .
                 State s u
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) 
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) 
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   
              -> m b
             }
```

Can we do it like this ?

```
newtype ParsecT m a s u     -- Only the order of s u m a is changed to m a s u.
    = ParsecT {unParser :: forall b .
                 State s u
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) 
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   
              -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b) 
              -> (ParseError -> m b)                   
              -> m b
             }
```

I am wondering whether there is a rule or principle about the order of type variables when we define a newtype.

Comment: A similar question at the value level is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863128/ordering-of-parameters-to-make-use-of-currying

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this case, `a` is last because we want `ParsecT s u m __` to be a monad, that way, what our parsers look for can depend on what they found before, and so forth.  If `u` came last we couldn't write

```
 instance Monad m => Monad (ParsecT s u m) where ...
```

`m` is next-to-last because we want `ParsecT s u` to be a 'monad transformer'

```
 class MonadTrans t where 
     lift :: m a -> t m a 

 instance MonadTrans (ParsecT s u) where ...
```

If we put the `m` first, this instance wouldn't be possible.  There doesn't seem to be any similar reason for the ordering of `s` and `u`.

Comment: Worth bringing up that `newtype` is sometimes used purely to manipulate the order of the type indices so that you can provide instances for `Functor` and `Monad` on multiple typed holes.

Comment: @applicative, thank you. I see now. I've tried but it is actually impossible to alter the order and preserve the original class-instance structure.