# Order of type-variables in instance-declarations

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a type `T a b` and I want to write an instance declarations e.g. an instance declaration for `Functor` that ranges over `a` and *not* `b`. Is this possible without defining a `newtype`?

I read [What is the rule of the order of multiple type variables in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860473/what-is-the-rule-of-the-order-of-multiple-type-variables-in-haskell) which leads me to believe that this is not possible, but this seems completely arbitrary to me.

What I'm hoping for is something like:

```
instance Functor (T * b)
```

Comment: You might be able to get away with `type Flip f a b = f b a` and `TypeSynonymInstances`, but really you should change the argument order or use a newtype instead.

Comment: @Lazersmoke: That won't work, since type synonyms need to be fully applied.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question directly but perhaps make it a Bifunctor so you can map over a or b or both?

Comment: @ppb 's suggestion is a good alternative. It also give you the option of using [`Data.Bifunctor.Flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html) (yes, it's a newtype, but at least it's one you don't have to define).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not arbitrary. It's how Hindley-Milner type inference works with higher-kinded types and curried type constructor application. Unification of type variables is based on the concept of generative type constructors.  That is, if `(f a) ~ (g b)`, then `f ~ g` and `a ~ b`, where `~` is type equality.

Let's apply that to unification of an expression like `(fmap f someT)`, for `someT :: T a b`.  I'll start by giving everything other than `someT` fresh type variables, to work the way unification does.

```
someT :: T a b
fmap :: (c -> d) -> f c -> f d
f :: e
```

By the fact that `fmap` is provided `f` as a first argument, we unify `(c -> d) ~ e`. So..

```
fmap f :: f c -> f d
someT :: T a b
```

This is where generativity comes into it.  From here, we see `(f c) ~ (T a b)`.  Let me add some additional parenthesis for clarity:  `(f c) ~ ((T a) b)`.  This is how type constructors work in Haskell - they are curried in the same way as term-level functions. By generativity, `f ~ (T a)` and `c ~ b`.

Then from that:

```
fmap f someT :: T a d
```

So it's necessarily true that the `Functor` instance must operate only on the second type argument of the type `T`.

Of course this all goes back to the type inference algorithm. You could give up Hindley-Milner or curried type constructors to make things work differently. But the result would be very different from Haskell in far more ways than just allowing a couple instances that Haskell doesn't.

Comment: Ahh. Stack overflow. One of the few places on the internet where people are genuinely​ helpful. Thank you very much for such and elaborate answer!