# How to make Either into a functor in second type

Tags: haskell, functor, either

I have been reading "Learn You A Haskell For Great Good!" and right now I am on "The Functor Typeclass" section.

Here they make Either into a functor by fixing the first type as follows:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
  fmap f (Left x)  = Left x
```

So I wanted to ask, how could I make Either into a functor in the first type (by fixing the second type) instead, so that, I get the following definition for fmap

```
fmap f (Left x) = Left (f x)
fmap f (Right x)  = Right x
```

Comment: That's impossible unless you define it as `data Either b a = Left a | Right b`.

Comment: Pay close attention to what they are doing; `Either` itself is not a functor, only the higher-kinded type resulting from the application of `Either` to an arbitrary type.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of other design choices made in Haskell.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139690/383200 for some further discussion of those design choices and why they lead to this result.

Comment: @chepner that is true, but can't we have some type level `flip` to do what @Willem Van Onsem said?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I had something similar in a different, deleted answer. It wasn't quite type-level, but defined a natural transformation `eswap :: Either a b -> Either b a` that could bracket the application of `fmap f`. (`leftmap f = eswap . fmap f . eswap`). Are you thinking of something analogous to `newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }`, like `newtype Flip f a b = Flip { getFlip :: f b a }`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't; `Either a` can be a functor because the partial application of `Either` has kind `* -> *`, but you can't do partial application from the right.

Instead, you might be interested in the [`Bifunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) instance of `Either`:

```
instance Bifunctor Either where
    bimap f _ (Left a) = Left (f a)
    bimap _ g (Right b) = Right (g b)
```

`bimap` takes two functions, one for each of the two types wrapped by `Either`.

```
> bimap (+1) length (Left 3)
Left 4
> bimap (+1) length (Right "hi")
Right 2
```

There are also `first` and `second` functions that focus on one or the other type. `second` corresponds to the regular `fmap` for `Either`; `first` is the function you are looking for.

```
> first (+1) (Left 3)
Left 4
> first (+1) (Right 3)
Right 3
> second (+1) (Left 3)
Left 3
> second (+1) (Right 3)
Right 4
```

---

(hat tip to @leftaroundabout)

The `Control.Arrow` module provides the `left` function, which effectively is the same as `second`, but with a more descriptive name and a different derivation. Compare their types:

```
> :t Data.Bifunctor.second
Data.Bifunctor.second :: Bifunctor p => (b -> c) -> p a b -> p a c
> :t Control.Arrow.left
Control.Arrow.left :: ArrowChoice a => a b c -> a (Either b d) (Either c d)
```

`second` is hard-coded to work with functions and can be restricted by `p ~ Either`. `left` is hard-coded to work with `Either` and can be restricted by `a ~ (->)`.

---

Confusingly, `Control.Arrow` *also* provides a `second` function which is similar to the `Bifunctor` instance for tuples:

```
> :t Control.Arrow.second
Control.Arrow.second :: Arrow a => a b c -> a (d, b) (d, c)

> Control.Arrow.second (+1) (1,2) == Data.Bifunctor.second (+1) (1,2)
True
```