# Could not deduce (a ~ Set.Set (Set.Set a))

Tags: haskell

I need help with the following error please. Basically for a given list of items I want to create a function that checks if an item is in that list. In order to do that I turn the list into a set and then create a closure around that set.

```
toAccept :: Ord a => [a] -> (a -> Bool)
toAccept xs =
    let xset = Set.fromList xs in
    let
    -- accept:: Ord a => a -> Bool
    accept x = Set.member xset x in 
    accept
```

What I am getting is

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Set.Set (Set.Set a))
from the context (Ord a)
  bound by the type signature for
             toAccept :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Bool
  at Tokens.hs:6:13-39
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for toAccept :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Bool
      at Tokens.hs:6:13
Expected type: a -> Bool
  Actual type: Set.Set (Set.Set a) -> Bool
In the expression: accept
In the expression: let accept x = Set.member xset x in accept
In the expression:
  let xset = Set.fromList xs in
  let accept x = Set.member xset x in accept
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the order of arguments in `member` backwards.

Comment: Shit! That was dumb. Thank you...

Comment: Also I hope you know about `elem`.

Comment: @n.m. If he's querying a lot of elements `elem` is `O(n)` each query but `toAccept` is `O(n)` during construction but only `O(log(n))` for each query.

Comment: you can also just replace your last four lines with ``(`Set.member` xset)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your arguments flopped

```
let accept x = Set.member x xset in accept
```

As a rule, In haskell functions the datastructure comes last since this makes it amenable to pointfree style. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863128/ordering-of-parameters-to-make-use-of-currying) for more on this.

A potentially nicer way of writing this is

```
toAccept' :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Bool
toAccept' = flip Set.member . Set.fromList
```

Here we take advantage of Haskell's currying feature, since `[a] -> a -> Bool` is the same as `[a] -> (a -> Bool)`. We can actually write our function as though it receives two arguments and doesn't take one and returns a function because in Haskell, these options are identical.