# Using mocks in unit testing in Haskell?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, quickcheck, hunit

Consider the following piece of code:

```hs
data Slice = Slice
  { text :: String,
    color :: Color
  }

newtype Color = Color
  { string :: String
  }

mainList :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath] -> [String] -> [[Slice]]
mainList somethingA somethingB codedLines = ...
```

The `Slice` record represents a result of decoding a string with ANSI escape codes.
Inside the `mainList` function I use some function, let's call it `categorize` that parses the `codedLines` (this represents a line of ANSI escape coded strings) parameter to `[[Slice]]`.

#### First question:

How would I write unit tests for the `mainList` function using the Quickcheck unit testing framework?
I am fairly new to Haskell. Now, if this had been some OOP language, I know what to do: have the class that has the `categorize` method passed as a parameter to the ctor of the class that has the `mainList` method and then mock my heart out of it using some mocking library or even write the mock manually. But what a man to do in Haskell, where there is no notion of classes?

#### Second question:

Maybe I can change the `mainList` function like follows:

```hs
mainList :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath] -> ([String] -> [[Slice]]) -> [[Slice]]
```

But then, I would have to pass it a mock instead of the third parameter. Since Haskell is not an OOP language, is there even a notion of a mock? Is this idiomatic Haskell? Or maybe I'm mistakenly projecting OOP principles onto a functional language?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to ask only one question. When you have multiple questions, ask them in multiple posts.

Comment: Your second question indicates you intuitively understand the idea of *dependency inversion*: `mainList` no longer depends on some hard-coded value `categorize` that you would need to patch, but rather uses whatever function of type `[String] -> [[Slice]]` you can provide; in production, that would be `categorize`, but for testing, it can be anything else under your control.

Comment: @chepner AKA (in this case) *higher-order functions* 

Comment: Incidentally, I would probably pass the `[String] -> [[Slice]]` parameter as the *first* parameter, because I feel it would be more common to keep the `categorize` strategy fixed and vary the filepaths than the reverse. You could partially apply with `categorize` and pass the resulting function to clients who don't care to know about strategy selection. http://wiki.haskell.org/Parameter_order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863128/ordering-of-parameters-to-make-use-of-currying

Comment: You should be a bit more concrete regarding what depends on what in your code. The way you describe it, it sounds like the way to go is to not write `mainList` as such at all, but instead two simpler functions that in the end are simply composed together. Now, I suppose there may be reasons why you can't do that in your actual applications, but then you should make them clear in the question.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, I thought about it before posting, but decided not to since the 2 questions are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How you could mock

You have correctly noticed that if you want to use different implementations of functions that are called by a function that you're testing, you can simply turn them into parameters instead of calling them directly:

```
mainList :: TypeOfCategorize -> [FilePath] -> [FilePath] -> [String] -> [[Slice]]
mainList categorize ... =
   ... categorize ...

mainListForTesting = mainList categorizeMock

mainListForProd = mainList categorizeReal
```

This is in fact the exact same idea of which "dependency injection frameworks" are a massively more complicated version. If you would like it to be more complicated in Haskell too you can apply any of the standard techniques used for managing additional pieces of information you need to pass around and don't want to manage so explicitly; the fact that you're doing this for testing purposes isn't hugely different from many other contexts in which this concern arises. A few thoughts off the top of my head:

1. You could use a single record-of-functions argument containing all of the functions you want to mock for testing (instead of a separate extra parameter for every function).
2. You could use `ReaderT` to make such a record-of-functions accessible without needing to be explicitly passed all the time. (This will only save you much if you have a lot of functions calling each other with the *same* set of implementations, rather than every function needing a different set of functions that could be mocks or real)
3. You could use a type tag to indicate what "purpose" the function is being run for (production or an extensible set of testing purposes, if you need more than one mock), and use type classes to provide the correct implementations for each purpose rather than explicitly passing them in.

But fundamentally it all boils down to: if you want to use different values on some invocations than on others, then those values are some form of parameter. And in Haskell, an implementation is a function is a value. So you use the same tools for getting different implementations into your `mainList` calls for testing purposes that you would for getting any other value into different `mainList` calls for any other purpose.

#### Should you mock?

You also ask whether "mocking" is idiomatic Haskell, and I would say the answer is "it depends, but largely no" (full disclaimer: I would **also** say that mocking is massively over-used in OOP testing too, so maybe my preferred ways of thinking about testing are just not to your taste).

`mainList` is pure (and is constrained to be so from the type, as long as we ignore `unsafe*` functions). That means that everything it calls is also pure. Almost all of the time, that means that there's no need to mock anything.

`mainList` will call `categorise` with some particular arguments, perhaps multiple times. To test that `mainList` does the correct thing, you need return values for those calls. Since those calls are pure, each of them has a single correct answer that is completely independent of anything else that is going on in your program; there's no state to setup, no side effects you might not want, no external environment required. If `mainList` uses anything *other* than the single correct return value for each call to `categorize`, then you're not testing `mainList`'s real behaviour, you're testing hypothetical behaviour when `categorize` returns something *other* than what it should; it's not going to do that in production, so testing what it does in those conditions isn't very useful. One way to get `mainList` to use the correct values so you can test the behaviour of `mainList` is to very carefully consider the test case you're running and work out what that correct answer(s) should be, and pass in a mock `categorize` that returns the correct answer(s) for this test case. But a far *easier* way is to just pass in the *real* `categorize` and let `mainList` get the correct answer from the function you wrote to *produce* the correct answers.

This does mean you might get a test failure from `mainList` that only happens because `categorize` returned the wrong result. But the tests for `mainList` aren't what guards against that vulnerability; the tests for `categorize` do that job! If you get test failures for `mainList` and `categorize` at the same time, just start debugging `categorize` first (which is a good idea **anyway**, in case your changes there require flow-on changes in the things that call it, including `mainList`). You're far more likely to get a false negative test from `mainList` from a bad mock than you are from the real `categorize`. After all `categorize` is the thing you are specifically engineering to return the correct result for `categorize` calls; no mock is ever going to be as likely to succeed as that job. And if the requirements for `categorize` change what the correct result is (either from external change or because something was misunderstood originally), you're much better off having the test for `mainList` pick up the changed `categorize` and detect whether that causes `mainList` to fail. If `categorize` is mocked then the tests for `mainList` will continue to pass against the *old* definition for what `categorize` is supposed to return, and then fail in production. The danger of mocks getting out of sync with real implementations that change is *much* worse than the danger of getting two test failures caused by one defect, in my opinion.

You might need to mock if:

1. The function you're testing calls things that depend on an external environment that isn't present in your testing environment (like a database, interaction with a user, etc, etc)
2. The function that you're testing calls things that have side effects that you don't want to happen in a testing environment (you should probably be able to test your logic for detecting when to automatically fire the missiles without actually firing the missiles)
3. The function you're testing calls things that take an impractically long time to really compute

In Haskell that's generally a pretty small minority of functions we want to test. Purity and the strong type system mean we're encouraged to have *most* of our code in pure functions, that can be tested independently of any external environment. Only a relatively small fraction of the code base *directly* deals with the external environment (rather than being parameterised on things that have been computed from it). And functions that take a long time are usually scaling with the size of some inputs, so they can be tested with smaller inputs that take less time.

So in Haskell mocking is not generally considered a core testing technique that should be applied to everything.

The mocking that we **do** do often isn't called or thought of as mocking. Using things like monad transformers or effect systems, we often write code that *does* depend on an environment or have side effects in a way that is polymorphic in the specific implementation of the effects. The motivation for this is usually talked about more in terms of getting better type safety and composability, but as a side effect (pun intended) it also means we can swap different implementations for testing. But this *isn't* used to mock out arbitrary pure functions called by pure functions under test.

#### Property-based testing, like QuickCheck

You mention "the QuickCheck unit testing framework". QuickCheck can indeed be regarded as a unit testing framework, but it usually isn't because it's a library for **property-testing**, which is a very specific kind of unit test (or isn't unit testing at all, depending on your definitions).

For property tests, you don't just write one specific test case and check that you get the expected output. Instead you write a property which is parameterised on some inputs and tests if the property holds; this needs to be a **general** test of the property regardless of the specific value of the input (so very different from a typical unit test where you check features of the output for specific known inputs). QuickCheck will then randomly generate *lots* of values trying to find one that falsifies your property; the test passes if it can't find one.

The standard trivial example (from the [QuickCheck docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html)) is:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

-- Reversing a list twice results in the original input list
prop_reverse :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_reverse xs = reverse (reverse xs) == xs
```

We didn't test this by checking that `reverse (reverse [1, 2, 3]) == [1, 2, 3]`, we wrote a property that will test that for **any** list of integers.

It's not my intent to talk a lot about property based testing, but I'm hoping that you might see why I bring it up in the context of your questions about mocks and testing with QuickCheck.

If you were using QuickCheck to test `mainList`, you would be writing **general** properties that should work for any random input that QuickCheck generates. This does not go very well with the idea of mocking the functions that `mainList` calls. We don't have a specific test case with known inputs and therefore known calls that should be made to `categorize`, so we can't just make a mock `categorize` that ignores its inputs and returns the values we expect `mainList` to get. In an ideal world, the generated inputs for `mainList` will do a decent job of representing every possible input and code path that `mainList` could face in production, so we'd **need** a mock `categorize` that can return the correct result for any possible call. We already have a function with that specification: `categorize`. Writing `categorize` a second time just to test `mainList` is a bad idea.

(If `categorize` has a tricky/fragile implementation for performance reasons, writing a more straightforward and obviously-correct implementation would be an excellent way to test `categorize` **itself**; just write a property test that the obviously-correct-but-slow implementation always returns the same thing as the fragile-but-fast implementation, for all inputs! But there's still no point using the second implementation in property tests of things that *call* `categorize`)

The popularity of property-based testing in Haskell is another reason why mocking is not such a common technique. If you have properties that actually do a reasonable job characterising what correct behaviour of a function looks like, then you generally can't test those properties without real implementations

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much @Ben for this long and detailed answer! I am still reading it and taking it all in.

Comment: Hmm... `or isn't unit testing at all, depending on your definitions` - this is an interesting line.

Comment: Finished reading. 2 times. I understand. I am accepting this answer. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker Lol, the "or maybe isn't unit testing at all" line wasn't supposed to be interesting! I just thought whether I said property testing was a different thing to unit testing or was specific subtype of unit testing I was likely to get someone disagreeing, and I don't actually care which way it's classified. So I was just trying to hedge my bet!

Comment: "So I was just trying to hedge my bet!" - I hear you, brother! Hedge succeeded :-)